# Convert Letter to Number

Tags: matlab, char, type-conversion

I'm new to matlab ... I simply would like to convert letter to numbers such that:

```
A=1
B=2
C=3
```

all my numbers are capital case. Off course, I could define constant for each char, but is there a shorter way?

Thanks!

Comment: Isnt this just a renamed version of your previous question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the `char` function.  You can give it an integer argument.

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/char.html